# Square notation for Lagrangian terms

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, notation

I am starting field theory and have questions regarding what I learned about tensor/Einstein notation.  I made up my own problem where I am deriving things backwards to practice tensor notation and manipulation.

Starting with the Lagrangian
$L = -\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$,
where $F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_{\mu}A_{\nu} - \partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}$.

So we have

$L = -\frac{1}{4} \left( \partial_{\mu}A_{\nu} - \partial_{\nu}A_{\mu} \right) \left( \partial^{\mu}A^{\nu} - \partial^{\nu}A^{\mu} \right) = -\frac{1}{4} \left[ \partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}\partial^{\mu}A^{\nu} - \partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}\partial^{\nu}A^{\mu} - \partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}A^{\nu} +  \partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}\partial^{\nu}A^{\mu} \right]$

Combining like terms gives

$L = -\frac{1}{4} \left( 2\hspace{1pt} \partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}\partial^{\mu}A^{\nu} - 2\hspace{1pt} \partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}\partial^{\nu}A^{\mu} \right) =  -\frac{1}{2} (\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu})(\partial^{\mu}A^{\nu}) + \frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu})(\partial^{\nu}A^{\mu})$

Now if we want to simplify this Lagrangian, the first term is clearly the square.  So we have

$L = -\frac{1}{2} (\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu})^{2} + \frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu})(\partial^{\nu}A^{\mu})$

For the second term, it is not so clear to me how to simplify it.  Since the derivatives each have different indexes, I can try

$\frac{1}{2} \left( \partial_{\mu}A_{\nu} \right) \left( \partial_{\rho}A^{\mu}\eta^{\rho\nu} \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left( \partial_{\mu}A^{\rho} \right) \left( \partial_{\rho}A^{\mu} \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left( \partial_{\mu}A^{\nu} \right) \left( \partial_{\nu}A^{\mu} \right)$

where I have re-index after the second equals sign.  So the Lagrangian is now

$L = -\frac{1}{2} (\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu})^{2} + \frac{1}{2} \left( \partial_{\mu}A^{\nu} \right) \left( \partial_{\nu}A^{\mu} \right)$

I have seen this Lagrangian written as $L = -\frac{1}{2} (\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu})^{2} + \frac{1}{2} \left( \partial_{\mu}A^{\nu} \right)^{2}$, but I don't understand how this make sense since there is no indication on the second term that $\frac{1}{2} \left( \partial_{\mu}A^{\nu} \right)^{2} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \partial_{\mu}A^{\nu} \right) \left( \partial_{\nu}A^{\mu} \right)$.  Is this just sloppy notation when people write the second term as a square?  Is it also true that one can never change a free index to another free index already in use in a term when one is raising and lowering the index?  Is my understanding of tensor notation correct?

Comment: Seen where? Which page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, writing it as a square is sloppy notation.

I am not sure about what you mean with "changing a free index to another free index already in use when raising/lowering indices". In general, replacing all occurrences of a free index with something else does not change the expression (even if afterwards two free indices are the same). I don't see how this relates to raising/lowering indices.

However, you cannot change a free (or dummy) index to a dummy index that's already in use (that is one that appears once in upper and once in lower position in the same term), as then the contraction structure of the term is no longer well defined). You can also not introduce a dummy index if the symbol is already in use.

Perhaps, it is an issue of nomenclature, for me a *free* index is one that is not summed over, but appears in the same position (upper/lower) in all terms on both sides of the equation – so it is an index that indices the components of the tensor you write an expression for. Indices that occur in upper and lower position in one term (and are thereby summed over) are *dummy* indices.

All in all, your understanding of Einstein notation seems solid.